# Search for a word inside a string in C

Tags: c, string

I have a newbie question right here and i want to learn with you.
I have a struct array , inside that array i have a string variable.
I want to count all the positions that have the word "string" inside the string variable.
My problem is that i don't know what string.h function use to search inside a string for a word and count it.

Hope you can help me .

Here is an simple example what i want.

```
struct _man
{
  char name[50];
  int house_number;
};


void main()
{
  int i=0,count=0;
  struct _man man[20];
  //assuming there is already information inside the array struct
  for(i = 0; i<20;i++)
  {
    if (//function i want to know to search for the word "Jose" inside string  man[i].name)
    {
      count++;
    }
  }
  printf("There is %d people with the word Jose in their name\n",count);
}
```

Comment: google for `strstr()`

Comment: [Searching for your *exact title*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Search+for+a+word+inside+a+string+in+C) yields more than enough to get you started. Please, do simple research before posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: i already googled it , and i saw a topic here with that answer but my problem is that i want to count every time the string have that word and what i learned on internet with strstr is that it only points to the position on the string where is the word

Comment: Did you consider that such a function might not exist, and you'd have to write it? Hint: Use a loop. Also, your title is misleading. You say you want to *search* for a substring, but you really want to *count instances of* a substring.

Comment: Although technically he *does* want to search for the first occurrence of the substring. Then the first occurrence of the substring after that. Then the first occurrence of the substring after that ;) </further hint>

Comment: @JoséPedroBrito Haha, take a rest, because posting this question probably took more time than inventing a solution under normal circumstances.

Comment: Thanks guys i solved my problem and learned something new , im going to sleep now ahah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) from `string.h`

Answer (score 1):

`strstr()` is what you need to use:

For example:

```
char * name = "Jose Pedro Birto";
char * toBeMatched = "Pedro";

if (strstr(name, toBeMatched)) {   // or (strstr(name, toBeMatched) != null)
    printf("name contains Pedro");
} else {
    printf("name does not contain Pedro");
}
```

Comment: C is not C++. Also, he wants to count.

Comment: The strstr(name, toBeMatched) is correct , thanks for your time ;)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `strstr()` is from C!  I am using C++ `cout` for output doesn't make my answer about using `strstr()` incorrect ok?  And, for "count", have you really read OP's question?  That counting is not part of question.  What he is asking for is just a way to see if a string exists in another.

Comment: really have no clue on the reason for downvote.  If people think it is irrelevant just because I used cout instead of printf, then lemme change that (but honestly that's stupid because that's not the main part of the answer)